# Generate multiple random letters to create a decryption effect?

Tags: javascript, random

I want create an effect like this [a link](https://dribbble.com/shots/4220958-xore-solar-system)!. (The name of the planet in the background)

So i need to generate many random letter before to display letter of my word one by one.

In my test, i try to display the word moon in my div.planet-name, letter by letter with a delay of 1000ms. And Before display a letter of Moon i want generate many random letter.

But when i use the function randomLetterEffect i stay blocked on the first letter and the word moon doesn't appear !

why i don't generate random letter in text.substring(0, 1), text.substring(0, 2), text.substring(0, 3), etc ... but only in text.substring(0, 0) ?

i try this :

```js
var text = $('.planet-menu').data('planet');
var letterChoice = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
var length = text.length;
var timeOut;
var timeOut2;
var character = 0;


(function typeWriter() { 
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
        character++;
        
        var type = text.substring(0, character);

        (function ramdomLetterEffect(){
            timeOut2 = setTimeout(function() {

                var type = text.substring(0, character);
                var randomLetter = letterChoice.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letterChoice.length));
                $('.planet-name').text(randomLetter);
                ramdomLetterEffect();

                if (character == length) {
                    clearTimeout(timeOut2);
                }

            },200);
        }());

        $('.planet-name').text(type);
        typeWriter();
        
        if (character == length) {
            clearTimeout(timeOut);
        }
        
    }, 1000);
}());
```

```html
<div class="planet-menu" data-planet="moon"></div>

<div class="planet-name"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am most grateful for your read !

Comment: Please specify what's your problem, where did you stuck, otherwise no one will be able to help you. Curretnly your topic looks like asking for full implementation or code review, and that might cause your question to be closed prematurely.

Comment: Here is a library:  https://github.com/dylanbfox/decrypt-effect and a demo: http://dylanbfox.github.io/decrypt-effect/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your problem, These issues are in your code:

**1-Check length of string before updating the text of class**

```
if (character==length) {
  clearTimeout(timeOut2);
  return;
}
```

**2-Update the text of class like this**

```
$(".planet-name").text($(".planet-name").text().substr(0, character) + randomLetter);
```

Working code

```js
var text = $(".planet-menu").data("planet");
var letterChoice = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
var length = text.length;
var timeOut;
var timeOut2;
var character = 0;

(function typeWriter() {
  timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
    character++;

    var type = text.substring(0, character);

    (function ramdomLetterEffect() {
      timeOut2 = setTimeout(function() {
        var type = text.substring(0, character);
        var randomLetter = letterChoice.charAt(
          Math.floor(Math.random() * letterChoice.length)
        );
        if (character == length) {
          clearTimeout(timeOut2);
          return;
        }
        $(".planet-name").text($(".planet-name").text().substr(0, character) + randomLetter);


        if (character == length) {
          clearTimeout(timeOut2);
        } else {
          ramdomLetterEffect();
        }
      }, 200);
    })();

    $(".planet-name").text(type);
    typeWriter();

    if (character == length) {
      clearTimeout(timeOut);
    }
  }, 1000);
})();
```

```html
<div class="planet-menu" data-planet="moon">
</div>

<div class="planet-name"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to write a very modular approach to generating this particular effect, that separates the effect itself from how it is rendered:

```js
const text = $('.planet-menu').data('planet')
const letterChoice = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

obfuscate({
  // required: input to obfuscate
  string: text,
  // 1s for each character
  // default is 1s
  duration: text.length,
  // 200ms for each frame
  // default is 60 fps
  fps: 5,
  // only lowercase letters
  // default is all printable ascii characters
  random: letterChoice,
  // consume characters in sequential order
  // default is random order
  next ([index]) { return index },
  // required: updates view
  render (string) { $('.planet-name').text(string) }
}).then(() => {
  // when effect is completed
  console.log('done!')
})
```

```css
.planet-name {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="planet-menu" data-planet="moon"></div>
<div class="planet-name"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/patrickroberts/9fe4606118237749749c7bffe95fc066/raw/8f04a89d79be0659f29a8900982db50794386ed9/obfuscate.js"></script>
```

However, I find that increasing the frame-rate of the randomly generated characters tends to make the effect look more aesthetically pleasing:

```js
const text = $('.planet-menu').data('planet')
const letterChoice = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

obfuscate({
  // required: input to obfuscate
  string: text,
  // 1s for each character
  // default is 1s
  duration: text.length,
  // only lowercase letters
  // default is all printable ascii characters
  random: letterChoice,
  // consume characters in sequential order
  // default is random order
  next ([index]) { return index },
  // required: updates view
  render (string) { $('.planet-name').text(string) }
}).then(() => {
  // when effect is completed
  console.log('done!')
})
```

```css
.planet-name {
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<div class="planet-menu" data-planet="moon"></div>
<div class="planet-name"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/patrickroberts/9fe4606118237749749c7bffe95fc066/raw/8f04a89d79be0659f29a8900982db50794386ed9/obfuscate.js"></script>
```